# How to change the position of a button when we have 2 forms in a single html page

Tags: html, css

I have 2 forms, one of which is to submit the user data ( 1st form ) and another to upload a file ( 2nd form. I cannot make it as a single form. My design is that way). First I want user to enter the basic information and then before hitting the submit button, I want that user to upload image and then hit the submit button. How can I make submit button of the 1st form to come after the 2nd form.

```
<form action="" method="post">  
<label>First name</label> 
<input type="text" name="firstname">  
<input type="submit" style="position:relative; top:120px; left:90%;" value="submit">   <!-- This button should come after 2nd form upload button -->
```

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<label>Upload a file:</label>  
<input type="file" name="pic" value=""><br>  
<input class="rel left30" type="submit" value="Upload">  
</form>
```

I have used CSS it changed the position though but I encountered my vertical scroll bar cut to half, making bottom half totally invisible.

Comment: Question: Should either of the form be invisible until the other has a value?

Comment: No form should be invisible. On click of upload, file should be uploaded and then the other user data should be submitted on click of submit button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a wrapper, you can better control its position using the wrappers boundaries and absolute positioning.

1) Below

The wrapper's `padding-bottom: 25px` is for the absolute positioned `input` to not overlap any elements that comes after the forms

```css
.formswrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  /* style for this demo only */
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.formswrapper form:first-child input:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="formswrapper">

  <form action="" method="post">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload a file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="pic" value=""><br>
    <input class="rel left30" type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>

</div>
```

2) Beside

```css
.formswrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.formswrapper form:first-child input:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="formswrapper">

  <form action="" method="post">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload a file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="pic" value=""><br>
    <input class="rel left30" type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, I would do the following:

CSS:

```
#button1 { display:none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button2", function() {
  $("#button1").css("display", "inline-block");
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```js
$('#userData').bind('keyup change', function(){
    var show = true;
    for(child in $(this).children){
        if(child.is(':empty')){
            show = false; //Could break here if you want. 
        } 
    }

    if(show){
        $('#upload').show();
    } else {
        $('#upload').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
#upload{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="userData" action="" method="post">  
<label>First name</label> 
<input type="text" name="firstname">  
<input type="submit" style="position:relative; top:120px; left:90%;" value="submit">
</form>


  <form id="upload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<label>Upload a file:</label>  
<input type="file" name="pic" value=""><br>  
<input class="rel left30" type="submit" value="Upload">  
</form>
```